# Is there a simple way to mix spring-mobile and apache-tiles to help use common elements?

Tags: tiles, spring-mobile

I've just setup a new application with spring-mobile and apache-tiles that I intend to used tile descriptors to help me reuse view components among the target platforms. I'm wondering if anyone has already done this and the best way to structure the application. Working with tiles in the past the tile descriptors add up pretty quickly, adding mobile and tablet into the mix and I could have easily twice as many.

So far I have a master tiles definition `WEB-INF/layout/tiles.xml` with three layouts in this area:

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="layoutStandard" template="/WEB-INF/layout/standard.jsp"/>
    <definition name="layoutMobile" template="/WEB-INF/layout/mobile.jsp"/>
    <definition name="layoutTablet" template="/WEB-INF/layout/tablet.jsp"/>
</tiles-definitions>
```

And then view definitions.

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="home" extends="layoutStandard">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="home.mob" extends="layoutMobile">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/home.mob.jsp" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="home.tab" extends="layoutTablet">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/home.tab.jsp" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

I've configured `mobileSuffix` and `tabletSuffix` against `LiteDeviceDelegatingViewResolver` so there isn't much headache in my controller, which also has `enableFallback` set which works well if I don't provide a mobile view definition.

Is there a way I can do something similar with the tiles configuration? i.e. if the view name ends in `.mob` then use `layoutMobile` instead of having to define it multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

I simply did the following:

**Add to applicationContext.xml**

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.mvc.DeviceResolvingHandlerInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

**Add to tilesDefinition.xml**

*n.b. requires tiles.el.jar*

```
<definition name="store" templateExpression="/jsp/home${layout}.jsp">
...
<definition name="page" extends="store">
...
```

**Add to controller**

I use a single method for all my controllers that fetches default data for all my pagetypes.

```
if (!device.isNormal() || sitePreference.isMobile()) {
  if (!sitePreference.isNormal()) {
    layout = "-mobile";     
  }
}
```

I only use the mobile, but you should be able to tweak this to work for mobiles or tablets.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Toby, wouldn't `LiteDeviceDelegatingViewResolver.mobileSuffix` be sufficient for you to not need the check? I could use the EL approach, however that would mean I can not use the fallback, correct?

Comment: The 'layout' characteristic in mine is only set when the mobile view is wanted, otherwise it's an empty string. For a more dynamic configuration, you could always use a java config such as http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?113701-Programmatic-Config-of-Tiles-with-Spring-3-1-Annotations